# Do I have to use browser login to use Google Sheets API from node instance?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I read all similar questions without arriving to the point.

I have a node instance and it runs on my "index.js" only in my local machine.

I have to take a cvs and put on new google sheet.

I have "credentials.json" in my project. Google say me "incorrect redirect_urls". But I cannot put a redirect url since it's a node script.

And I do not want to pass in a browser for a login. This because maybe tomorrow I will put the same script on a real server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the Google Sheep API I'm pretty sure you are not getting the results you want. ;)

Assuming you have enabled the Sheets API in you project, and you plan to use a server to deploy the application, then you need to configure you consent screen accordingly.

During development you can use localhost as a redirect URL, which will enable you to test the app.

You should have a read through [this help article](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en) to correctly set up your OAuth credentials and consent screen for each type of project.

Comment: I already tried with localhost, and the result is that chrome arrives in a page that doest not exist and I cannot find the code required to use in the terminal for the next steps ;)

Comment: can you share the code you are using? remove sensitive info.